# Android: application global onPause() and onResume()?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, lifecycle

Is there something like an application global `onPause()` and `onResume()`?

My main activity listens for GPS fixes, which I want to continue working when switching to another screen/activity. Therefor I cannot unregister my `LocationListener` in the activity's `onPause()`. However I still want to unregister my GPS listener when switching to another application (so save battery) and turning it back on when returning to my application, regardless what screen/activity the user is currently in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there something like an application
>   global onPause() and onResume()?

No, sorry.

> My main activity listens for GPS
>   fixes, which I want to continue
>   working when switching to another
>   screen/activity. Therefor I cannot
>   unregister my LocationListener in the
>   activity's onPause(). However I still
>   want to unregister my GPS listener
>   when switching to another application
>   (so save battery) and turning it back
>   on when returning to my application,
>   regardless what screen/activity the
>   user is currently in.

Here's one possible approach:

Step #1: Move the `LocationListener` logic into a `Service`, which the activities connect to via the local binding pattern or something. Also have at least one service call `startService()`, so an `unbindService()` won't cause the `Service` to go away (assuming you're using the local binding pattern).

Step #2: Have the activities call into the service during `onPause()` and `onResume()`.

Step #3: Have the service maintain a reference count of outstanding activities.

Step #4: When the reference count reaches zero, have the service arrange to get woken up via a Timer and `TimerTask`. Also, cancel any such outstanding `TimerTask` if the reference count gets incremented.

Step #5: Have the `TimerTask` shut down GPS if it ever gets executed.

The net is that you will only release GPS after such-and-so amount of inactivity. That inactivity could be for any reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for that detailed explaination.

Comment: Also new to API 14, ActivityLifecycleCallbacks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/13809991#13809991

Comment: is this answer still the same for 2016>? a global activity lifecycle would be very useful!

Comment: @androidPlusPlus: you can use this library called [Foredroid](https://github.com/steveliles/Foredroid)

Answer (score 8):

Use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks). Register it in your Application:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = Unit
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) = Unit
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity resumed: $activity")
    }
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity paused: $activity")
    }
    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) = Unit
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) = Unit
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) = Unit
})
```

Comment: If I wanted it across whole app do I have to call this in every single application?